# Is it possible to make drupal 7 module work in drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal-6

I Want to use a module in drupal 6.
There is a module called RABBIT HOLE which is only available for drupal 7.x. 
Is there a way i can use this module for 6.x.  What will be the modifications i would need to do to the 7.x module.  I have little knowledge about creating drupal 6 modules.

Comment: any views or ideas and suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 3):

Apologies upfront for not putting this as a comment (don't have the rep yet). I will phase this as an answer, hopefully it will help.

Looking at the Rabbit Hole (RH) module, it seems as though there is a serious emphasis on *entities*. Entities were introduced in Drupal 7 (see: https://drupal.org/node/1261744).
As such, the way that the RH module is organized is around a data structure that simply doesn't exist in Drupal 6. 
Converting it would therefore require that you rewrite the module to use Nodes only, jettisoning the Entities api references.

There seems to have been some work done on porting it back to Drupal 6 though. 
I can't vouch for the release, but at the very least you can see some example code showing how  a port might be achieved here https://drupal.org/node/1492304

Comment: thank u @bomoko i had found that module earlier. But as u knw the support for D6 is becoming less. Thats why i wanted to knw in general what changes i can make to a D7 module to use in D6..... well i knw upgrading to D7 would be the best answer.... thank u very much for ur feedback